# How to SEO friendly an existing ASP .NET 3.5 web application under IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis, seo, url-rewriting, url-routing

So, I know there's a lot of this subject here and over the Internet. But most articles/questions refers to "static" url rewriting, like:

```
www.site.com/products.aspx?category=Books
```

So they rewrite it to

```
www.site.com/Products/Books
```

That's ok but I need something else.

The site is like a CMS, it has different types of content.

Nowadays to read the article titled "How StackOverflow helps you in your development" you need to go to an URL like the following.

```
www.site.com/viewContent.aspx?Id=1234
```

What I want to achive is:

```
www.site.com/Content/Articles/how-to-stackoverflow-helps-you-in-your-development
```

So as I understand, I need to involve ASP .NET in that, because first I need to retrieve the article (an its title of course) and then rewrite the URL.

But I'm wondering how the hell ASP .NET will know how to get that article if I go to that URL, it doesn't include the id anywhere...
So maybe I could accept something like

```
www.site.com/Content/Articles/1234/how-to-stackoverflow-helps-you-in-your-development
```

I'm kind of lost here really.. I've never done any URL Rewriting at all and I've googled a lot and I cannot find a way to do what I want. Maybe what I want is not called url rewriting??? I don't know...

The site is running under Windows 2003 Server, IIS6, ASP .NET 3.5 SP1
And of course, I need a free solution, cannot spend 100usd on the ISAPI mod (besides I don't know if that is going to do what I need).

Thanks to all and sorry if this is a duplicated question, but I couldn't find it.

**EDIT**: I don't need to support non-ASP.NET files (jpgs, gifs, etc) don't need to be rewritten. I just need to rewrite the viewContent page to include the content title into the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the new [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) that comes with ASP.Net 3.5 sp1 to have clean URLs.

This can even be done in web forms and not just MVC. ( I have done it myself). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.extremeaspnet.aspx) and [here](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/) for exanples of how to set it up.

You can throw the Id of the article and the title in the URL and make the Id the real parameter that gets used to search for the article. That is what SO does. Try removing the question for the URL and it will take you to the same place.

Even if you don't use the Id you can pass the title of the article "how-to-stackoverflow-helps-you-in-your-development" to your DB and retreive the article based on the title.

With regards to IIS 6 it is a little trickier since IIS 6 by default can't handle extension-less URL's.

There are a few work arounds:

1. Use the wildcard mapping in IIS to map all requests to Asp.Net
2. Put Default.aspx at the end of your urls

See this [post](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) for other possible solutions.

Although the first solution may have performance issues if all content in your site goes through Asp.Net (even images, css, .html ...) in a small site it shouldn't matter. I have used this approach and there wasn't any major performance issues. I think it is the simplest solution. Here is the [website](http://www.merlenorman.com) I built with it

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I will go for your approach. So I will be using just .NET to rewriting right? I don't need any IIS addon or filter right?

Anyway I will include the id in the url because the title is not a unique column so there could be more than 1 content object with the same title.

Thank you, I'll try it and let you know!
vote up for you =)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not having any luck with it. I've read all of your links but I cannot make it work. I don't fully understand how it works really. I've followed the steps on the first link you wrote but I cannot make it work. 
I've set the Route, RouteHandler and everything. But question... do I need to rewrite every link on my site to point to the new "virtual" url? Isn't a way to add some code to the viewContent.aspx page to rewrite the url? But I guess I'd need the other way around when people copy that url... I'm kind of lost really. WHEN do I get the content title and put it in the url???

Comment: Forgot to mention that I don't mind including ".aspx" in the url... I'd prefer that rather than wildcard mapping to avoid performance issues.
So a url like www.mysite.com/content.aspx/1234/this-is-the-content-title would be enough to me. But I don't understand where I need to actually get the parameters and "pass" them to the routing class.. I'm lost =(

Comment: Did you download and run Chris Cavanagh's code. You can download it here. http://aspnet35routing.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx
If you want to only using routing in your site then any existing link in your site would have to be in the form of one of your routes (www.site.com/Content/Articles/how-to-stackoverflow-helps-you-in-your-development).So you would have to fix all of your old links. I have only recently learnt routing recently so maybe someone else has other suggestions.
I can't write too much here. You can email me at: olevin at merlenorman dot com.

Comment: I'm still fighting with it. So there's no option to have the 2 links? The old one and the new routed one? Btw, the link you paste is broken...

Answer (score 2):

This one is free, I have used it and it works pretty well: http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF

The nice thing is that it will handle url's without an extension (i.e. .aspx, .html, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with ASP.NET routing.You can do this with ASP.NET MVC as well as Webforms.No need to do anything with IIS.

Check the below link

https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx#postadlink

I did URL routing in my web application within 1 hour with the details from the above link.Its quite simple to learn .They provide sample codes too.It will help you to do it easily

You can retrieve the Id of the content using the title.But title should be unique.You can use ajax to check whether the title is a already existing one when user takes mouse out from the textbox.

Comment: Thanks, but titles are not unique, and it shouldn't be. What I want is just a way to rewrite the URL, without losing the old URL. As far I understand this is not possible using ASP.NET routing.
I mean... I want to have both: www.site.com/Content/Articles/1234/how-to-stackoverflow-helps-you-in-your-development and www.site.com/viewContent.aspx?Id=1234. If that's not possible, I would have to rewrite every link on the site, and people already may have favorited some... so that's not an option. Am I being clear? =P
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add a http module to your current webforms project.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

This shows you the basics of it, But it can easily be expanded so that the pages you want to rewite is taken from a database or even built on the fly.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best way. Again I need to ask if my "old" url will be still available (I mean the viewContent.aspx?Id=1234) and then when they enter through that old url, the page will rewrite it to include the content title. And then I need the viceversa... from the "rewritten" url (which will include the id of course) get the id and then load the article from the db as normal.

Comment: Yes with the rewritter as I use it the old url will still work and display the page. But if you have back links, you will want to add something to check the 'old' URL's and then redirect then to the new SEo friendly, or you run the chance that the google spirders will find the same page content on two diffrent URL's which is very bad.

Answer (score -1):

[ASP.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) is your friend for that

stackoverflow use MVC

Comment: The site has been done intially in plain ASP, then migrated to ASP .NET 1.1, then 2.0, then 3.5. It's a big site, I cannot re-make the whole site with MVC just to include the SEO friendly urls...

Comment: Really?? How? I've read/seen several ASP .NET MVC tutorials and they all start from "new project -> ASP .NET MVC project".... So how can I mix it?

Comment: after you created a new project, right click on the project and add new item then select asp.net webform

Comment: That would be similar to migrate the project, I still need to create a new empty MVC project and add every webform? I don't think that's a good approach, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I didn't try the other way around but it should be easy, just look at the difference between a webform and mvc web.config from that point on, you just need to create the folder structure / reference mvc dll

Comment: -1: It is not a viable solution to change a big site to a use MVC, just because you want the SEO-URLs