# how to show dynamic html page instead of aspx page with query string variables

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, seo

we are using framework 3.5 please let me know how can I achieve following

instead of showing

http://www.mydomain.com/microsite/index.aspx?projid=3&adid=5

I want to show something like

http://www.mydomain.com/[cityname]/[keyword]/[customer-project-name]/index.html

where [cityname],[keyword],[customer-project-name] will be dynamic based on projid, adid

we want to do this for SEO

Comment: Take a look ASP.NET URL rewrite - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Urlrewritting to make your pages more Url / user friendly.

Please consider reading below mentioned articles and that may be helpful to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

[How to SEO friendly an existing ASP .NET 3.5 web application under IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987871/how-to-seo-friendly-an-existing-asp-net-3-5-web-application-under-iis6)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a HttpModule which rewrite the url or use a existing Url Rewriting Module like [UrlRewriter.net](http://UrlRewriter.net) . [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) is a blog post about this subject.